# Github-action:- Process completed with exit code 255

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I am trying to run a nodejs code while when running cypress run command the error msg i get is exit code 255.

In workflow i am using selfhosted runner with a container image

Comment: Can you please share a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Added the details

Comment: Please update your question (you have added an answer). Also, please be mindful of formatting to make sure everybody can read it well.

Answer (score -3):

> e2e@1.0.0 cypress
> cypress run --config defaultCommandTimeout=10000
> [840:0720/095901.667270:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is
> ====================================================================================================
> (Run Starting)
> ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │Cypress:        9.6.1                                                                          │
> │Browser:        Electron 94 (headless)│
> │Node Version:v16.14.2 (/usr/local/bin/node)│
> │Specs:1 found (homepages.js)│
> │Experiments:    experimentalStudio=true                                                        │
> └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> Running:  homepages.js(1 of 1)
> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
> npx browserslist@latest --update-db
> Why you should do it regularly:
> https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
> Error: Process completed with exit code 255.

Code:

cypress-run:
runs-on:
- self-hosted
# container: cypress/browsers:node12.18.3-chrome87-ff82
env:
DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://localhost:2376"
container:
image: cypress/base:16
# options: --user 1000
# needs:
#     - build-cypress-image
steps:
- name: Checkout
uses: actions/checkout@v2
# - name: Install node
#   uses: actions/setup-node@v2
#   with:
#      node-version: '14'

```
  - name: Install dependencies
    working-directory: web/e2e
    run: |
      npm ci
      npx cypress verify
      npx cypress info
      npx cypress version
      npx cypress version --component package
      npx cypress version --component binary
      npx cypress version --component electron
      npx cypress version --component node
      cd cypress
      ls -lrt
  - name: Cypress run
    # uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
    working-directory: web/e2e
    run: |
      npm install cypress@9.6.1 --save-dev
      npm run cypress
```